# Usage of Polymer 1.0 paper-styles Element

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0, paper-elements

Unfortunately, I'm finding the current documentation/examples for the usage of paper-styles a bit lacking.  I'm not an experienced CSS guy (relative newbie actually), so I could really use examples of how to implement Polymer 1.0 application-wide styling in order to be used by all of it's custom elements (i.e. by applying classes to any tags in those custom element's local DOMs).  I did this kind of thing relatively easily in Polymer 0.5 using core-styles, but it has changed enough in 1.0 to confuse me, particularly without full docs/examples to work from.  It also seems there may be a few ways to accomplish this.  I'm also wondering if paper-styles is still considered experimental in 1.0?  There are no docs or examples for it's use in polymer 1.0 online element catalog (https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-styles), although I did come across 'some' on it's gitHub repository.

Comment: `paper-styles` is just similar to an `app-theme.html` file. You just import it on your project and the custom properties it defines will be applied and/or can be used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One thing you can do when documentation is lacking is search through other projects that are using the code you would like to use.  `paper-tabs`, for example, uses `paper-styles`.  You can see an example import of `paper-styles/color.html` in `paper-tabs.html`.  The value `--paper-yellow-a100` is being used in `paper-tabs.html`.  Below is an example of using various CSS variables (`var`) and mixins (`@apply`) defined in `paper-styles` to apply style to the main document.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>paper-styles Example</title>
    <script src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="import" href="bower_components/polymer/polymer.html" />
    <link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-styles/paper-styles.html" />
    <style is="custom-style">
        .shadow {
            @apply(--shadow-elevation-16dp);
        }

        section {
            background-color: var(--google-blue-700);
        }

        p {
            @apply(--paper-font-display3);
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <section class="shadow">
        <h1>Example</h1>
        <p>
            This is an example using <em>paper-styles</em>.
        </p>
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

[Click here to learn more about styling in Polymer 1.0.](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/styling.html)

Concerning your question about paper-styles being experimental, on the [Polymer home page in the catalog section](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/#catalog) it states:

> Custom elements, built by the Polymer team, ready to use in your
>   applications.

However, in various locations on the site, including [styling](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/styling.html#custom-css-mixins), there are mentions of experimental features.

> the custom properties shim included in Polymer includes an
>   experimental extension

At this time using `@apply` would be considered experimental.

There is a page on the Polymer website titled [Experimental features & elements](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/experimental.html) you can look at for more information.

Answer (score 5):

The general misunderstanding seems to be, that just by importing the `paper-styles` element, the document gets styled according to the material design specs. That's not the case.

**You just get all the variables and mixins**.

Then you need to apply them to each and every element inside your custom-element the way you see it fit.

Here is an example element:

```
<dom-module id="demo-element">
    <template>
        <style>
            :host {
                display: block;
                background: var(--paper-blue-500);
                padding: 20px;
            }

            .title { @apply(--paper-font-title); }

            button { @apply(--paper-font-button); }     
        </style>

        <h1 class="title">Hello World</h1>

        <button>Demo</button>

    </template>
    <script>
        Polymer({
            is: 'demo-element'
        });
    </script>
</dom-module>
```

Luckily the styles are nicely structured inside **just four files** with each just a couple of hundred lines max.