# Jupyter/Declarativewidgets: Applying css styles?

Tags: polymer, jupyter

This is probably an extremely simple question for somebody knowing HTML/CSS just a tiny bit, so upfront, apologies but I couldn't find anything online (and I'm not sure where to look exactly). Specifically, I want to have some basic paper-styles applied to some of the widgets. In this case it is the `secondary` text attribute, depicted at the top (mostly) here: https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-styles?view=demo:demo/index.html&active=paper-styles

I want to use this to style the second line of a paper-item. I also posted an issue on the github repo of jupyter/declarativewidgets with more information (code snippets), please see [here](https://github.com/jupyter-incubator/declarativewidgets/issues/427). Any help/pointer/tip/explanation would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you're declaring `secondary` as a class, not an attribute, e.g. `<div class="secondary">` not `<div secondary>`  You may also need to import the paper-styles .html file with a `<link>` tag?

Comment: or maybe it's not that simple... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31465141/usage-of-polymer-1-0-paper-styles-element

Comment: the CSS rule for `.secondary` doesn't even exist in the paper code, you apparently have to create the CSS rule yourself based on variables prefixed with `--` in the theme file.  You'll want to look at [the demo](https://github.com/PolymerElements/paper-styles/blob/master/demo/index.html#L115) on that paper-themes doc you referenced to see how it's done.  Yah, pretty complicated!

Comment: Thanks Adam for your replies! Still no luck: I added a ```<link rel="import" href="urth_components/paper-styles/paper-styles.html"
        is='urth-core-import' package='PolymerElements/paper-styles'>``` and then simply copied over the complete style section of the linked demo (and have ```class="secondary``` applied).

Comment: How would the most simplest example look like if I want to test wether the CSS styling actually works?

Comment: It looks like the CSS variables used in the paper-styles demo only work within Polymer elements (not sure exactly why yet — perhaps by design?)  Here's a [simple example notebook](https://gist.github.com/peller/63b6bf6ccb2d37247f714273117cc4c1) showing a CSS rule for `.secondary` applies to a div inside a custom Polymer widget instance.  If you want to use variables used internally in Polymer to external HTML elements, I'm not sure if that's possible...

Comment: I updated the [example in gist](https://gist.github.com/peller/63b6bf6ccb2d37247f714273117cc4c1).  Revision 2 works with a simple div.  I forgot the `is="custom-style"`